# Running Java Web App with HANA Database locally

Tags: java, eclipse, hana, sap-business-technology-platform

I just started working on a Java web application using SAP Cloud Platform with a HANA Database, and I don't fully understand how to test it locally.

I managed to create and successfully deploy the web app on SAP Cloud Platform, using a HANA Database, with Spring MVC and Hibernate. What I want to know is if there's a way to run the application locally, connecting it to the same database.

I've read plenty of tutorials and it seems that I need to install the SAP Hana Cloud Tools for Eclipse and connect Eclipse to the database (which I did), and when I run the app on the local server, it should connect to the database, but it doesn't.

How should I proceed? Do I need to somehow replicate the database locally or I can connect to the database in the cloud? Is the SAP Cloud Connector related to this? Which is the standard way of working with this platform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours searching, I finally got it. In case someone else is struggling with this:

You need to configure the connection.properties file of you local Tomcat Server (Server > Java Web Tomcat 8 Server-config/config_master/connection_data), to point to the right database. The usual configuration parameters for HANA are:

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver=com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver
javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:sap://<host>:<port>/?reconnect=true&autocommit=false // you need to connect to your cloud database with HANA Studio in Eclipse first. Mine ended up being localhost:30015
javax.persistence.jdbc.user=db-user
javax.persistence.jdbc.password=db-pass
eclipselink.target-database=HANA
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually also use the webapp/META-INF/context.xml to store the connection settings. The content could be:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/HANA" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="username" password="password" driverClassName="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:sap://myserver:31215" />
```